# Database First MySQL Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this database made in MySql Workbench, how can I use Entity Framework to generate automatically all the models I wrote in SQL, inside the proper project folder called "Models" ? Do I need some NuGet packeges ? Should I run any commands in the terminal?

Thank You for all the support, this is my first stackoverflow question

These are my tables in MySQL Workbench :

```
create database lakeydivolta;

use lakeydivolta;

create table users(
    Username varchar(767) primary key not null,
    FirstName text,
    LastName text,
    Dob datetime,
    Adress text,
    Email text,
    PhoneNumber text,
    HashedPassword varbinary(4000),
    PasswordSalt varbinary(4000)
);


create table videogames(
    Id int primary key auto_increment,
    Title text,
    Description text,
    Platform text,
    Poster text, -- verrà inserito l'url della locandina di gioco
    Price double,
    ReleaseDate datetime,
    CDKey text
);


create table bought(
    primary key(UserUsername,VideoGameId),
    UserUsername varchar(767),
    VideogameId int,
    foreign key(UserUsername) references users(Username) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    foreign key(VideogameId) references videogames(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Comment: Check this url: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @Lambdat check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70040468/9925593)