# how do we scaffold just 1 schema from a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to run the following command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=..........;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Schemas "dbo"
```

Getting the following exception:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ProductInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
PM>
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do we create c# models from the database?**

Comment: Nothing related but is surprising for me, a 49.9k still using dbo :S

Comment: I would say that you have mismatch in some nuget/tools package versions. Try updating packages to latest 3.1 version and install latest 3.1 version of tools (check the reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`). Check [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19012) out.

Comment: Try EF Core Power Tools....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my snippet.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t tabl1 -t table2 -t tableN -c "SomeContext" -d
```

> The --schema option can be used to include every table within a schema, while --table can be used to include specific tables.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0):

for scaffold a schema use this :

```
-schema yourSchemaName -Force
```

and for multiple use this

```
-schema yourSchemaName1 ,yourSchemaName2 yourSchemaName3 -Force
```